# How to add pem file to the main folder of .apk in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

Is there a way to include a file to the main folder of .apk in android xamarin

I'm using a library which required a .pem file that is located in the main of .apk file.

Seems the only way is to add it in Resources/raw.

But the requirement is to add it on the main folder

I want to include my.pem file to the main directory of the .apk file like in the image below

[image: sample file structure]

Comment: That is a picture of what? Eclipse? Android Studio ? Which version? And why dont you show the main folder?

Comment: This is a picture from Android Studio Build->Analyze-APK. This is extracted from the APK file.

Comment: Use the StackOverflow image uploader instead of linking to some facebook cdn site. We can't see the image. Why do you have the arbitrary requirement to have the .pem file in the root of the apk file? Assets is where it probably should be. You can always copy it to somewhere else at runtime if needed.

Comment: I know the right place to add it is on resources/raw dir, but I'm using different library which asking me to place it under main directory and i don't have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you do not have the option to add a file in the apk root through Visual Studio (for Mac). But if you have a build script that builds your apk you are able to add it through that script. One way to do so could be the following:

1. Build the apk
2. rename the apk file ending to zip and extract that file into a folder
3. add the file to the extracted folder
4. zip that folder again
5. run zip-align and jarsigner again.